# Laravel 4 Model Methods access

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

am I doing something wrong to be able to access Methods stored in a model in a view. For Example. My User model has a method that looks like

```
    public function isCustomer(){
        if (isset($this->customer_id)) 
        return true;
        else return false;
    }
```

When I try to access this in the view I end up with `Call to a member function getResults() on a non-object.`

View code is something like

```
@if($user->isCustomer)
Something
@endif
```

Is the model ONLY for database relationships between models or can I store my own class functions here as well?

The function i listed is one of the basic ones. I have quite a few more complicated functions that I would like to run from my User class but am not sure how, as i end up with the same error each time. Should they be stored in the controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store class functions there. By first glance it looks like your missing () on isCustomer. If it were me I would store that in the controller, like:

```
$customer = $user->isCustomer();
```

then pass that to the view.

Comment: Thanks, I had this same issue when I called $user->save; instead of $user->save().